# Parsing a text stream with one word in each line in BASH

Tags: bash

I have a text stream which has n lines and each line is one word.

I would like to write something like a for loop that `VAR` gets at every iteration the i'th line (from line 1 until EOF) and to run a command on each.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases the `xargs` command can be sufficient:

```
my_stream_generator | xargs -n1 my_command
```

This assumes that the way of passing the words from the stream to the command is by specifying that word as an argument for the command.

If this is not the case @aioobe's suggestion might be more suitable for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
while read VAR
do echo $VAR    # just print the word on the line
done
```

Add `< yourfile.txt` after `done` if you need to read the words from some file.

[ideone.com demo](http://ideone.com/5sFL2)

Comment: Not working for me. I don't have a file. I have a stream of text that I got out of running a cut command. I tried putting it in a variable but it still didn't work